# Cannot launch AVD in the Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

While running emulator, it shows an error.

Cannot launch AVD in the emulator.

Output:
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.sse4a [bit 6]

How to resolve it?